# Redis HA what happens if Master stops and restarted

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

In a Redis HA setup, with 1 master and 5 replicas:
Let's suppose the master goes down. Then the Sentinels would elect a replica as the next master.

What happens when the original master is restarted with its config? Would it be joining as a master or as a replica? I suppose, since it is not configured as a replica, so it should not be running as a replica.

Answer (score 1):

When the original master is down and a new master is elected. The original master will be added as a *virtual* replica of the new master. When it recovers, original master will be set to be a replica of the new master automatically.

Comment: Any link from redis.io ?

Comment: https://redis.io/topics/sentinel

Comment: what do you mean by "virtual" replica?

Answer (score 1):

Master would join as a replica.

...The master will then demote itself to a replica...
https://redis.io/commands/failover